# Solving inequality using matrix form condition

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

*answer is $x=(10,5)^T$
(a,b) is inner product.
x and y is 2d vector.

> Find $\bar{x}$ within the area by the systems of inequality,$K(x)$ s.t.
>
> About inner product of vector F(x) and (y-x),
> $F(\bar{x})^T.(y-\bar{x}) \geq 0$ 
>    For Any $y$ in $K(\bar{x})$
>
> $F(x)=a.x-b$
>  $K(x)=\bar{K}\space and \space \hat{K}$
>   $\bar{K}=c.y-d\leq 0$
>  $\hat{K}=e.y+g.x-h\leq 0$

first,setting the matrix and vector

```
a = {{2, 8/3}, {5/4, 2}};
b = {{34}, {24.25}};
c = {{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}};
d = {{0}, {11}, {0}, {11}};
e = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
g = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
h = {{15}, {15}};
```

so I want to do like the following)

```
y = Array[yy, {2}];
x = Array[xx, {2}];
cond1 = # <= 0 & /@ Flatten@(c.y - d);
cond2 = # <= 0 & /@ Flatten@(e.y + g.x - h);
F = Transpose[a.x - b];
target = First@Flatten@(F.(y - x));
SomeFunction[target>=0, And @@ Join[cond1, cond2]]
```

=>

```
{xx[1]->10,xx[2]->5}
```

how to solve the inequality F.(y-x)>=0 using cond1 and cond2?
this returns error:

```
Solve[{target >= 0, List @@ Join[cond1, cond2]}, Join[x, y]]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Added:
Because this kind of dual problem should be treated as a multi-step decision problem, I use this as the answer to the question.

> $L(y,x):=F(x)^T.(y-x)$
>  $L(y,x)\geq 0 \Rightarrow minL(y,x)\geq0$

*Avoiding the case of minL==0*,
because of constraints.

```
Table[{s, j, 
     First@Flatten[
       NMinimize[{(target /. {xx[1] -> s, xx[2] -> j}), 
         List @@ Reduce[
           And @@ Join[cond1, cond2] /. {xx[1] -> s, xx[2] -> j}, y]},
         y]]}, {s, 0, 15}, {j, 0, 15}] // Flatten[#, 1] & // 
  Select[#, Last@# > 0 &] & // First@SortBy[#, Last@# &] &
```

> {10, 5, 1.77636*10^-15}

Answer (score 4):

Using your definitions of a, b, c, d, e, g, h, target, cond1, cond2, you can find the minimum value of target (under the constraints) using NMinimize:

```
NMinimize[{target^2, Join[{cond1, cond2}]}, Flatten[{x, y}]]
{3.29871*10^-22, {xx[1] -> 7.92824, xx[2] -> 6.96093, 
                  yy[1] -> 0.530959, yy[2] -> -0.455972}}
```

I don't think this is exactly what you are looking for, but it might help to get you started.